# QThread signal does not emit at the end of the thread

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qthread

I'm creating a GUI that makes HTTP requests using requests library. I'm trying to dynamically update the status of each request and thus need to actively Poll the request. I created a Worker class which defines the on-start function to perform and a separate complete function to handle the completion phase of the thread. With some debugging I determined that the start-signal works and the thread does indeed run. However, the finish.emit() does not work (or the connect function never calls the completion function). I'm relatively new to PyQt and Qthread but here is the current code I'm running.

**worker class & completion function:**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QObject, QCoreApplication


@pyqtSlot()
def complete():
    print("hello")


**Worker class & function**
# An object containing methods you want to run in a thread
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, process):
        super().__init__()
        self.process = process

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        # your code
        while self.process.poll() is None:
            QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            print("do something")
        # Emit the complete signal
        self.finished.emit()
```

The piece of code I'm running to check these signals in my main py folder. Just to cover background information in case it is relevant to the issue. The following code (thread creation) occurs when a function thats ran once a button is clicked. Essentially the user pre-sets some configurations on the UI and hits "send" which is where this piece of code begans:

```
def sendButtonClicked(mainWin, advWin, uiProg):

        #...OTHER CODE...

        result = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'requestBoron.py', '-id', devID, '-p', settings], shell=False)
        time.sleep(2)
        thread = QThread()
        worker = pollingThread.Worker(result)
        worker.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.started.connect(worker.run())
        worker.finished.connect(pollingThread.complete())
        thread.start()
```

Any help, tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are 3 important problems with the code above: 1. the most critical: you're not connecting the function, you're directly running it in the main thread. Remove the parentheses from `worker.run`, and also from pollingThread.complete: signals are connected to *references* of callables, you should not call them; 2. if `sendButtonClicked` is in the main window class, remove `time.sleep`; 3. the thread has no reference, and will probably get garbage collected as soon as that function returns, so you must create a persistent reference for it (add it to a list, set its parent, etc).

Comment: Then: Qt slots require a QObject subclass (just like signals), the decorator you used for `complete` is useless. If you need to execute and communicate with an external process, you can use [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) which not only already supports signals natively, being it a QObject subclass, but it also allows asynchronous execution; `processEvents()` only works in the calling thread, so if you expect it to work for other thread in order to allow UI update/interaction, you're wrong (it probably works right now because you're *not* executing it in the external thread).